# How can I add a dynamic number of columns to my query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query listing some statistics about document writers:

```
select   d.WrittenBy,
         count(1) as NumDocs,
         sum(case when d.Language = 'English' then 1 else 0 end) as English,
         sum(case when d.Published = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as NumPublished
from     #documents d
group by d.WrittenBy
```

In reality, `#documents.Language` contains many more languages than just English:

```
English
French
English;French
German
French;German
```

Etc. A distinct on `#documents.Language` may return a different result in a week from now because someone inserted new values.

I would like to include all languages in my statistics:

```
select   d.WrittenBy,
         count(1) as NumDocs,
         sum(case when d.Language = 'English' then 1 else 0 end) as English,
         sum(case when d.Language = 'French' then 1 else 0 end) as French,
         sum(case when d.Language = 'English;French' then 1 else 0 end) as EnglishFrench,
         ...
         ...
         sum(case when d.Published = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as NumPublished
from     #documents d
group by d.WrittenBy
```

However, this requires me to manually update the query every now and then. I would instead like to have the query update automatically when new languages become available:

```
declare @cols as nvarchar(max);

set @cols = stuff
    (
        (
            select distinct ',' + quotename(Language)
            from   #documents
            for    xml path(''), type
        ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''
    )
```

This gives me the list of all possible `Languages`. And here I am stuck. I would like to dynamically add these language columns to my table:

```
WrittenBy   NumDocs   English   French   EnglishFrench ... Numpublished
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Linda          10        5        2           1        ...      4
Peter           8        0        0           6        ...      0
```

How can I accomplish this? Any help is greatly appreciated, also if it means involving another temp table to join against (although, for learning purposes, I would prefer dynamic sql).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...in that you're ready for a little dynamic SQL...give this a twirl:

```
set nocount on
declare 
    @sql nvarchar( max ),
    @expression nvarchar( max ),
    @template nvarchar( 256 ),
    @language nvarchar( 128 )

select @expression = '';

declare c cursor for select distinct language from #documents
open c
    while ( 1 = 1 )
    begin
        fetch next from c into @language
        if ( @@fetch_status != 0 ) break
        select @template = 'sum(case when d.Language = '''+ @language +''' then 1 else 0 end) as ' + replace(@language,';','')
        select @expression += @template + ','
    end
close c
deallocate c

select @sql = 
'select   
    d.WrittenBy,
    count(1) as NumDocs,
    '+ @expression +'
    sum(case when d.Published = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as NumPublished
from     #documents d
group by d.WrittenBy'

execute ( @sql )
```

One little trick I'll explain...be sure to initialize `@expression` to an empty string before you start your loop...otherwise it'll be null...and adding to null just makes more null ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Clay! I will try this as soon as I'm back at work. One question though -- could you explain the `while (1 = 1)`? 1 always equals 1, so I would expect this loop to last forever. Yet, it could not because of `@@fetch_status` at one point not being equal to 0. So how do I interpret `1 = 1` in this context?

Comment: You're right it's just a "forever loop"...the condition will always be true. There's no `while( true )` in tsql. It's the `if ( @@fetch_status !=0 ) break` that exits the loop when the data runs out.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL 2008 and up, you can use PIVOT or UNPIVOT. See more info here : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx